# finest time resolution in as3?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

If I want to measure the amount of time that has passed in as3 between method calls.  Is the highest resolution from:

```
var now:Number = new Date().getTime();
```

?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [getTimer](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/utils/package.html#getTimer%28%29)() method.

> Returns  — The number of
>   milliseconds since Flash Player was
>   initialized. If the player starts
>   playing one SWF file, and another SWF
>   file is loaded later, the return value
>   is relative to when the first SWF file
>   was loaded